# How do I properly display the data from an object within an object?

Tags: java, linked-list

Creating a linked list that has a class, Notes, that's basically an object that contains NotePages, another class, that contains Strings that are "title" and description. The class Notes extends another class which is the LinkedList class mentioned earlier. The problem is that when I try printing out the Notes with a note page in it, the display comes out like this:

```
Note one 
     []
```

Assigning what to display in the object looks like:

```
NotePages page = new NotePages("title one", "Description");
Notes note = new Notes("Note one", page);

note.printNote();
```

I've tried creating other methods such as a String method to try and return the page properly to no avail.

Here's my code for the Notes object.

```
public class Notes extends LinkedList{

private String title;
private LinkedList<NotePages> pages;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public LinkedList<NotePages> getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public void setPages(LinkedList<NotePages> pages) {
    this.pages= pages;
}

public Notes(String title, LinkedList<NotePages> pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.pages= pages;
}

void printNote(){
    System.out.println(getTitle()+"\n"+getPages());
}
}
```

I need the display to output something closer to this:

```
Note one 
    title one
    description
```

Here is the NotePages Class:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class NotePages {

private String title;
private String description;
private Color label;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Color getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(Color label) {
    this.label = label;
}

NotePages(String title, String description, Color label){
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.label = label;
}

NotePages(String title,String description){
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

void printPage(){
    System.out.println(getTitle() + "\n     "+ getDescription());
}

}
```

Comment: where are you setting the notePage to Note?

Comment: I've set it to the constructor for Note, I may have left a typo that I have already changed I apologize for that.

Comment: I shall add it now

Comment: did you compile it? new Notes("Note one", page) should give you an error due to the definition: public Notes(String title, LinkedList<NotePages> pages)

Comment: Ah I see, I will try some more experimenting and see where I'll end up.

Comment: try changing Notes(String title, NotePages pages) and inside this.pages = new LinkedList<NotePages>(); this.pages.add(pages); inside NotePages add toString method to print attribute as you want

Comment: Creating the ones inside isn't possible for me since a colleague has made the LinkedList and abstract class instead. As to why he made it abstract I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

**The change will need to be made in printNote function.**

When the constructor for Notes is initialized **pages** variable gets initialised with a NotePage LinkedList. 
pages does not contain the values directly. It contains objects of NotePage. So you need to use a loop for traversing through all the linkedList objects and then print the title and description for every object.

```
void printNote(){
     System.out.println(getTitle());

    //no need to use getPages function, pages already has your list

    for(int i=0; i<pages.size();i++)
          System.out.println(pages.get(i).getTitle()+"\n"+pages.get(i).getDescription());       

}
```

get function will help you get the object at every ith index and then simply use the get functions of your NotePage class to print title and description.

Also the in main function add a linkedList object to the constructor of Note instead of a NotePage.

```
LinkedList<NotePages> notelist = new LinkedList<>();
notelist.add(page);
//adding LinkedList object to Notes constructor
Notes note = new Notes("Note one", notelist);
```

Comment: I seem to have a problem, when using the method it would say that it cant resolve the methods of getTitle and getDescription

Comment: Have you created these getters and setters in your NotesPage class?

Comment: Also are these files all in same package?

Comment: I have and yes they are all within the same package. The problem is that it's looking for the getters and setters within my Node class instead of the NotesPages class

Comment: I think it relates to us creating our own Linked List instead of using the class itself.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload your classes ? Because it should not search within Note class as pages is a linkedlist of NotesPage class.

Comment: No that's not the issue.I'm sure of that.. I have tried this code and it runs.

Comment: You can try to use pages.get(i).printPage() function directly inside the for loop instead of getters

Comment: I will try uploading the classes and try the suggestions you've made.

Comment: Sure! Let me know if I can be of help in some way or other! Good luck

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I cannot find a way to upload the class by itself so I will just add it within the post.

Comment: Separate LinkedList class is not needed! Simply import util package in Notes class. Rest changes I already have mentioned! Can't find any problem with code though. Looks good and should work too  Did you try printpage function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198781/discussion-between-joey-deguzman-and-sakshi-vij).